# newbie with regex, parsing one and only one character

Tags: regex

i have to validate strings like:

```
10y9m12od or 9m12od or 12d or 10y9m or 9m
```

those are correct.

These are not correct:

```
10d2m5y, 2m5y10d...
```

As you can see, order of elements is important but elements are not mandatory...

I have this regex which I think it is fine but...:

```
([\d][yY]{1})?([\d][mM]{1})?([\d][o]{0,1}(d|D){1})$
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You only allow 1 digit before each letter. It should be `\d+[yY]`. And there's never any need for `{1}`, since that's the default.

Comment: And most regexp engines allow you to specify case-insensitive matching, so you can write `y` instead of `[Yy]`.

Comment: `{0,1}` can be written as `?`

Comment: If you only have one character or escape sequence inside `[]`, you don't need the brackets. So `[\d]` is the same as `\d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(\d+[yY])?(\d{1,2}[mM])?(\d{1,2}o?[dD])?$
```

1. You need to allow more than one digit before each letter. Years can be any number of digits, months and days can be 1 or 2 digits.
2. There's no need to wrap `\d` and `o` in `[]`.
3. You need a `^` anchor at the beginning.
4. There's no need for `{1}` to match a single repetition, that's the default for all patterns.

Comment: This should be the correct one, isn't? ^(\d+[yY])?(\d{1,2}[mM])?(\d{1,2}o?[dD])?

Comment: Correct, I was missing `)?` at the end.